# xSQL trace file error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use this programme that goes by the name xSQL Profiler but the problem is that it keeps giving me a error where it says:

```
Trace mietrak did not start. Please check if the Trace File Path You specified for each Sql Server exists. Also check if you can connect to the Sql Server and have ALTER TRACE permissions.
```

This error pops up when i try to play my trace.

So what i did is the following:

- I checked if the data path was correct and if it existed and it did
- I logged in as a sa on the SQL management studio and clicked on the security tab then the log in tab then the login for the machine i was using witch was production\production-server and under securable i granted it access to Alter trace
- after my second step failed i decided to let the program log in as a sa by choosing the SQL server authenticated mode and it still gave me the same error
- I reinstalled the program twice and followed all steps precise to no victory
- I then tried another profiler and it worked perfectly just to test if there is maybe some kind of SQL related issue

So now you are thinking why am i not just using the Profiler that works and that is because it does not offer all of the Features that xSQL does.

So please if any one has a solution or knows of a free profiler that is as good and offers the same features as xSQL please help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the location where the trace files are temporarily stored should be accessible from the server where the SQL Server instance you are tracing is running – SQL Server generates the trace and should be able to store the trace data in that location. [xSQL Profiler](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_profiler/) will then grab those files from there and load them into the central repository. 
If you still have trouble download and install the latest build from our site and then contact us at the support email so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

try not saving the result of the trace to a file and make sure you have the necessary permissions to run it. I assume you are trying to run on a production DB for example. Developers usually dont have permission to do that on production